# Merge_left function of 2048 game

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to define a `merge_left` function on the game 2048 and this is what I have come up with:

```
def merge_left(mat):
    score=0
    def helper(row,a):
        if not row:
            return a
        x=row[0]
        if len(row)==1:
            return helper(row[1:],a+[x])
        return helper(row[2:], a + [2*x]) if x == row[1] else helper(row[1:], a + [x])
    store=[]
    for row in mat:
        merged = helper([x for x in row if x != 0], [])
        merged = merged + [0]*(len(row)-len(merged))
        store.append(merged)
        score+=accumulate(lambda x,y:x+y,0,merged)
    def is_true(store):
        if store==mat:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    return (store,is_true(store),score)
```

However, for the `score`, I only want the sum of the values of all newly formed tiles, not the sum of all of the numbers. How can I filter them out so that I will only add up the newly formed tiles?
Should I use iteration instead of recursion in this case?

Example:

```
merge_left([[2, 2, 0, 2], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 8, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 2]])
#([[4, 2, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 8, 4, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0]], True, 4)
```

Please help. thank you!

Comment: Maybe it is better to send this question to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dataman No. CR is not suitable for this question.

Comment: You have to update score whenever    `return helper(row[2:], a + [2*x]) if x == row[1]`  is executed

Comment: @monster thanks for the reply. but do I update the score in a recursive call? i'm able to when faced with an iterative function but i'm not so sure about recursions.

Comment: @elle the simplest way is to delcare score global and replace the above if statement by  
 `if  x== row[1]`

 `score+=2*x`

 `return helper(row[2:], a + [2*x])`